# Why are some MSIE user agents not showing us .NET when clicked from a .NET app?

Tags: .net, user-agent

We have a .NET app that we've deployed to some systems. We also have a URL that we assume is only published via our .NET app and not known on any other page. We are tracking user agents with MSIE in them and sending them to a file. When we check the file, yes, the predominent number of them have .NET in the user agent string. But a few of them do not. For instance:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; BOIE9;ESMX)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/5.0)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
```

I guess we can make only two conclusions from this. One would be that our assumption that the registration page is accessible from some other link on the web (like Google found it). Another would be that someone has changed their user agent string with some tool/plugin/extension. Still another would be that some IE versions, even with .NET installed, do not announce their .NET in the user agent.

Our question to you is -- is there a case where .NET is installed, and MSIE is in the user agent, and it doesn't send us the .NET versions, if we assume that someone hasn't altered their user agent string with a fake string?

Comment: You should keep in mind that the url is visible in wireshark...

Comment: It's just a registration/payment URL. We ran a study and found on our download page (a separate URL) that 61% of our connections didn't have .NET in their user agent if they had MSIE. So, we then tried to verify the study by taking our .NET app's registration/payment URL (which is unpublished on the web) and check user agents from there, and only tracking MSIE connections. We're seeing most have .NET, but a few are not showing .NET in the user agent, which befuddles us.

Comment: Our goal is to figure out which versions of .NET the largest number of our customers have installed. But when we found that 61% didn't even have .NET but had MSIE, that was shocking. So, we just needed to validate that study, and now we're thrown for a loop because some of the MSIE user agents sent to us via a .NET app are showing no .NET, which seems theoretically impossible.

Comment: Note that we're also only tracking those connections from MSIE. We are aware that only Firefox tells us .NET, and at that, unreliably. But MSIE, we thought, would tell us reliably. That is, unless someone is able to alter their user agent, or something else is going on.

Comment: Proxies or antivirus software might alter the user agent string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft states in the link below that as of IE9, they stopped putting feature tokens for .NET in the user agent because they said it was breaking functionality on some web servers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx

...but as one other user mentioned above, proxies and antivirus software can sometimes alter the user agent string too, and so can some plugins/addons/extensions.